# replace <br> \n or spaces on a specific position inside a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

need to clear a textarea content
any combination of `br`, `\n` or `spaces` before and after `* * *` should be raplaced by  `\n\n`
pls help

```js
 var story = $('#story');
$('button').on('click', function(){
 let a = story.val();
 a = a.replaceAll("<\p> + zero or multiple br, \n or spaces + * * * + zero or multiple br, \n or spaces + <p>", "<\p>\n\n* * *\n\n<p>");
 story.val(a);
});
```

```css
#story{
display:block;
width:100%;
height:99px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='story'>
<p>lorem</p>
//here can be zero or multiple br, \n or spaces. should be replaced by \n\n
* * *
//here can be zero or multiple br, \n or spaces. should be replaced by \n\n
<p>ipsum</p>
</textarea>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
var story = $('#story');
$('button').on('click', function(){
 let a = story.val();
 a = a.replace(/(?:\s|<br>)*\* \* \*(?:\s|<br>)*/i,"\n\n* * *\n\n");
 // a = a.replace(/<\/p>.*\* \* \*.*<p/si,"</p>\n\n* * *\n\n<p");
 story.val(a);
});
```

```css
#story{
display:block;
width:100%;
height:99px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='story'>
<p>lorem</p>
//here can be zero or multiple br, \n or spaces. should be replaced by

<br>

* * *



//here can be zero or multiple br, \n or spaces. should be replaced by \n\n
<p>ipsum</p>
</textarea>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

There is some uncertainty with regards to "wild text", i. e. text-nodes that are not within a paragraph. These texts will remain where they are at the moment. If you also want them to dissappear you will need to do something like this:

```
a = a.replace(/<\/p>.**\* \* \*.*<p/si,"</p>\n\n* * *\n\n<p");
```